# Using :not() to ignore clicks on children links?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In a script I'm writing with JQuery I'm trying to add a click handler to a div, but ignoring clicks on the children `a` tags inside it.

You can see a JSFiddle of how I'm currently trying (and failing) to make it happen here: http://jsfiddle.net/q15s25Lx/1/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(document).on('click', '.post:not(a)', function(e) {
         alert($(this).text()); 
   });
});

<div class="post">This is some <a href="#">text</a> in a div. Click me please.</div>
```

In my real page, the `a` tags all have their own click handlers, so I need to be able to listen for those concurrently.

So, ideally I'd like to use something like the :not() selector to ignore clicks on this particular handler.

Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to add another handler that acts on the anchor and stops the event from propagating:

```
$(document).on('click', '.post a', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Without this, when you click the `a` the event bubbles up to the parent `.post`, and the handler fires on that anyway.

Comment: This worked perfectly! I expected it to cancel out my other listeners, but it did not. Thanks! As soon as I can I'll mark this as the answer.

Answer (score 3):

You need to stop event propagation to child elements using `.stopPropagation()`:

```
 $(document).on('click', '.post a', function(e) {
      e.stopPropagation();
 });
```

### Working Demo

Answer (score 0):

Try to stop the event from bubbling up the DOM tree using stopPropogation()

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click', '.post a', function(e) {
          e.stopPropagation();
          alert($(this).text()); 
    });
});
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/q15s25Lx/4/)

Comment: He wants the opposite of this. Have the alert fire when clicking the span, but not when clicking the anchor.

Comment: Ah i see thanks for the heads up, ill modify my answer

Answer (score 0):

Just `return false;` in the end of event handler.

```
    $(document).on('click', '.post', function (e) {

        alert($(this).text());//will show entire text
    });
    $(document).on('click', '.post a', function (e) {

        alert($(this).text());//will show 'text'
        return false;
    });
```

working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/q15s25Lx/2/

> `return false` will server as both `e.preventDefault()` &
>   `e.stopPropagation()`

Answer (score 0):

All of the other posts did not explain why your code failed. Your selector is saying : Find an element that has the class post and is not an anchor. It is NOT saying if a child was clicked and was an achor do not process.

Now there are two ways to solve it. One is to prevent the click from bubbling up from the anchors. You would add another listener on the anchors.

```
$(document).on('click', '.post a', function (evt) {
    evt.stopPropagation();  //event will not travel up to the parent
});

$(document).on('click', '.post', function (evt) {
    console.log("Click click");
});
```

Or the other option is not to add a second event, but check what was clicked.

```
$(document).on('click', '.post', function (evt) {
    var target = $(evt.target);  //get what was clicked on
    if (target.is("a")) {  //check to see if it is an anchor
        return; // I am an anchor so I am exiting early
    }
    console.log("Click click");
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Or jsut let jquery handle it all for you. `return false`

```
   $(document).on('click', '.post:not(a)', function() {
         alert($(this).text()); 
         return false;
   });
```